# Why is encoding of character 'ó' different?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

On my website I am trying to encode a text that contains polish regional characters:

```
string testPL = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("ęółźżćńą");
```

I would expect that none of these letters would be changed - after all, this function should escape only characters such as `'`, `<`, `>`.

However, instead of `"ęółźżćńą"` I get `"ę&#243;łźżćńą"`.

What is so different about the letter 'ó'? Is there any way to use this function without encoding this letter?

Comment: Why is it a problem? You have to anyway use methods to convert string to html and back.

Comment: characters between ASCII 160 and 255 (in this case `ó`) are always encoded https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs,f0f99ddd66f61359